# Load single entity without relations jpa

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have two entities students and grades. There is a one to many relationship between them. But when I make an api call to get students, I get all grades with them. Is there a way to load only student entity ? I tried FetchType.LAZY but it did not work.

Student model:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Student {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(
        strategy= GenerationType.AUTO,
        generator="native"
)
@GenericGenerator(
        name = "native",
        strategy = "native"
)

private Long id;

@NotBlank(message = "Name cannot be null")
private String name;

@NotBlank(message = "Lastname cannot be null")
private String lastname;

@NotNull(message = "Age cannot be null")
private int age;

@NotBlank(message = "Email cannot be null")
private String email;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "student")
private Set<Grade> grades =  new HashSet();
}
```

Grade model:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Grade {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(
        strategy= GenerationType.AUTO,
        generator="native"
)
@GenericGenerator(
        name = "native",
        strategy = "native"
)

private Long id;

private String subject;

private double value;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "student_id", nullable = false)
private Student student;
```

Student service :

```
@Service
public class StudentService {

private final IStudentRepository studentRepository;

public StudentService(IStudentRepository studentRepository){
    this.studentRepository = studentRepository;
}

public List<Student> GetAll(){
    return studentRepository.findAll();
}
```

Hibernate output:

```
Hibernate: select student0_.id as id1_1_, student0_.age as age2_1_, student0_.email as email3_1_, student0_.lastname as lastname4_1_, student0_.name as name5_1_ from student student0_

Hibernate: select grades0_.student_id as student_4_0_0_, grades0_.id as id1_0_0_, grades0_.id as id1_0_1_, grades0_.student_id as student_4_0_1_, grades0_.subject as subject2_0_1_, grades0_.value as value3_0_1_ from grade grades0_ where grades0_.student_id=?
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it did not work"? Did you check the generated SQL? Generally, if you have a lazy association, it should not get fetched. But remember, each object you fetch is a *managed entity*, i.e., a proxy. If you call the getter for a lazy association, it will be fetched

Comment: Yes, the first query selecting the student and second grades. Do you think problem is in getters ? In which entity ?

Comment: No, not saying that. I'm just thinking, maybe you have a different understanding of what Lazy loading is and maybe your code calls a getter, or a toString() or anything that accesses grades? Lazy loading only means, that loading will be deferred until the data is requested (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#JPA_Relationship_Types)

Comment: Also note that equals(), hashCode() and other methods can trigger lazy loading if not careful. Maybe read this: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/
And also consider a unidirectional ManyToOne from Grade to Student.
(and basically read anything and everything from Vlad Mihalcea to master JPA)

Comment: Maybe. Just in asp.net core if I wanted to join two entities I used linq and include method. If I don't want I just get single entity. I need to learn java for internship and it really confuses me.

Comment: I don't know Linq, but anyway this isn't just Java, but JPA. Get the basics of JPA down first. You might want to check the Wikibook link I posted earlier. Think of objects you get from your Persistence Context as managed proxies. Their state is managed by JPA, any change may trigger a DB write, touching any attribute may trigger a read.

Comment: If you set a debug break point right after the `findAll` call, do you also see the lazy loading happening? Chances are, the lazy loading happens due to you using the collection afterwards.

Comment: I don't know how the validation integration is working or what validation implementation you are using, but at the end of a transaction(maybe after `findAll`), it would happen that JPA/Hibernate validates the object.

Answer (score 0):

To load only the student entity, you can create a separate projection like `StudenDTO` and use it to pass across repo-service-controller.

The relevant part of projection is here

```java
interface StudentDTO {
    String getName();

    String getLastname();

    Integer getAge();

    String getEmail();
}
```

Now when you hit `localhost:8080/students/create-dto-return?id=1`

You won't see the next query being fired and this is triggered jackson during serialization.

Entire code is as below:

```java
package com.example.demo;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/students")
public class StudentsController {

    private final StudentService studentService;

    @Autowired
    public StudentsController(StudentService studentService) {
        this.studentService = studentService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public Iterable<Student> list() {
        return studentService.list();
    }

    @PostMapping
    public Student createEntityReturn(@RequestBody Student student) {
        return studentService.save(student);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/create-dto-return")
    public StudentDTO getByDto(@RequestParam("id") Integer id) {
        return studentService.findStudentOnlyByIdDto(id);
    }


    @GetMapping(value = "/create-entity-return")
    public Student getById(@RequestParam("id") Integer id) {
        return studentService.findStudentById(id);
    }

}

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Entity
class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    @NotBlank(message = "Name cannot be null")
    private String name;

    @NotBlank(message = "Lastname cannot be null")
    private String lastname;

    @NotNull(message = "Age cannot be null")
    private int age;

    @NotBlank(message = "Email cannot be null")
    private String email;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "student")
    private Set<Grade> grades = new HashSet<>();

}

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table
class Grade {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String subject;

    private double value;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_id", nullable = false)
    private Student student;
}

@Service
class StudentService {
    private final StudentRepository studentRepository;

    @Autowired
    StudentService(StudentRepository studentRepository) {
        this.studentRepository = studentRepository;
    }

    @Transactional
    public Student save(Student student) {
        return studentRepository.save(student);
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Iterable<Student> list() {
        return studentRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public StudentDTO findStudentOnlyByIdDto(Integer id) {
        return studentRepository.findStudentById(id);
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Student findStudentById(Integer id) {
        return studentRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Unable to find student"));
    }
}

interface StudentDTO {
    String getName();

    String getLastname();

    Integer getAge();

    String getEmail();
}

@Repository
interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Integer> {
    StudentDTO findStudentById(Integer id);
}
```